# Actualizar valores de un while usando ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, bucles, while

Tengo un problema con un while en PHP, este genera una tabla y cada fila tiene un modal que es el que quiero actualizar. Este es el código del modal, en él busco capturar los datos para luego enviarlos con ajax a otro archivo y actualizarlos.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editar<?php echo $id ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #0b2739 !important;">
    <h4 class="modal-title" style="color: #fff; text-align: center;">
     <font color="#fff"> Actualizar Producto</font>
    </h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body" id="cont_modal"> 
    <div class="row row-sm-offset">
     <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" readonly required="" id="id">
     <div class="col-md-10 multi-horizontal" data-for="name-form1-2">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="nombre_actual">Nombre actual</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control text-white" value="<?php echo $motivo; ?>" data-form-field="nombre_actual" id="nombre_actual" readonly>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10 multi-horizontal" data-for="name-form1-2">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="motivo">Nuevo nombre</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="motivo" data-form-field="motivo" required="" id="motivo">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>  
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="actualizar">Guardar cambios</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Este es el código del ajax:

```
$("#actualizar").click(function() {
            id = $("#id").val();
            motivo = $("#motivo").val();
            console.log(id);
            $.ajax({
            url:"ajax/ajax_motivo.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{id:id, motivo:motivo},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $.notify({
                    icon: "tim-icons icon-simple-remove",
                    message: "Hubo un error al insertar los datos."
                }, {
                    type: "warning",
                    timer: 600,
                    placement: {
                    from: "top",
                    align: "right"
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $.notify({
                    icon: "tim-icons icon-simple-remove",
                    message: "Error al enviar los datos."
                }, {
                    type: "warning",
                    timer: 600,
                    placement: {
                    from: "top",
                    align: "right"
                    }
                });
                console.log(data);
            }
            });
        })
```

Se ejecuta al apretar el botón con id=actualizar da cada modal... El problema es que solamente se actualiza la primer fila de la tabla, con los demás no me deja enviar los datos.
Entiendo que el problema es porque cada botón y cada id de los campos del modal, llevan el mismo nombre, pero he probado cosas que he encontrado y ninguna me funciona.
Alguien podría iluminarme en cómo puedo hacer por favor

Comment: que tiene que ver esto con php?

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es la repetición de **id** en todos tus modales. Cuando ejecutas el botón "Guardar cambios" tan solo coge el primero de ellos aunque esté escondido.

Prueba realizando estos cambios:

1. En el HTML:

- Donde pones esto:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" readonly required="" id="id">
```

pon esto:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" readonly required="">
```

pues no necesitamos el `id="id"` ya que hemos agregado el `id` como clase.

- Cambia esto:

```
<label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="nombre_actual">Nombre actual</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control text-white" value="<?php echo $motivo; ?>" data-form-field="nombre_actual" id="nombre_actual" readonly>
```

por esto:

```
<label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="nombre_actual<?php echo $id ?>">Nombre actual</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control text-white" value="<?php echo $motivo; ?>" data-form-field="nombre_actual" id="nombre_actual<?php echo $id ?>" readonly>
```

Este cambio es por coherencia, pues aparentemente antes también funcionaba, pero no podría asegurarte si funcionaría en todos los navegadores pues el id estaba repetido en todos los modales.

- Cambia esto:

```
<label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="motivo">Nuevo nombre</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="motivo" data-form-field="motivo" required="" id="motivo">
      </div>
```

por esto:

```
<label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="motivo<?php echo $id ?>">Nuevo nombre</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control motivo" name="motivo" data-form-field="motivo" required="" id="motivo<?php echo $id ?>">
```

por lo mismo que en el punto 2. Es decir, para quitar los **id** repetidos.

- Cambia esto:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="actualizar">Guardar cambios</button>
```

por esto:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary actualizar">Guardar cambios</button>
```

para que podamos invocar a este botón por clase, y no por id (por lo de siempre, no repetirlos).

2. En el javascript cambia esto:

```
$("#actualizar").click(function() {
            id = $("#id").val();
            motivo = $("#motivo").val();
```

por esto:

```
$(".actualizar").click(function() {
  id_modal = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id')
  id = $("#" + id_modal + " .id").val()
  motivo = $("#" + id_modal + " .motivo").val()
```

así primero descubrimos el *id* del modal gracias a situarnos en el **div** del modal mediante la subida por la jerarquía de elementos gracias a [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/#parent-selector) de jquery.  Y luego ya podemos usarlos para encontrar los elementos que tienen las clases **.id** y **.motivo** dentro de el y conseguir sus valores para la correcta ejecución del ajax.

Ya nos diras si te ha servido.